# Get checkbox values in given range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

I'd like to create a function that returns 2D array containing checkbox values in given range:

- `true` if checked
- `false` if unchecked
- `null` if no checkbox

[image]

```js
function getCheckboxInfo(range): {
  const sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  range = sheet.getRange(rangeA1);
  return /* (boolean|null)[][] */
}
```

Although I found similar methods for values (`range.getValues()`) or notes (`range.getNotes()`), I haven't found anything like that for checkboxes. The only solution I got so far doesn't look very optimal

```js
return range.getValues().map((row, i) => {
  return row.map((_, j) => sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).isChecked())
});
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Checkboxes are a type of data validation. Get the data validations with range.getDataValidations() and find if the validation criteria matches the constant SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX -- here are some examples of this: https://tanaikech.github.io/2021/12/23/checking-whether-cells-on-google-spreadsheet-have-checkboxes-using-google-apps-script/

Comment: Solutions belong in answers, not in edits to the question. This question, however, is off-topic since it asks an opinion-based question.